# How do you replace with a newline using gsub?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following:

```
str = str.gsub(re, '<pre><code>\1</code></pre>'
```

Which outputs:

```
<pre><code>        stuff...
```

I would like for `<pre><code>` to be on its on line by itself. How can I insert a newline character there? If I enter `\n` it shows up as HTML.

Answer (score 7):

Newline characters need to be enclosed by double quotes. With double quotes you'll need an extra backslash for the pattern match:

```
str = str.gsub(re, "<pre><code>\n\\1\n</code></pre>"
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `'\n'` is "literal-slash, n" while `"\n"` is "newline". Inside single quotes the backslash characters are not special, excepting `\'`.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation can help simplify the problem and avoid the leaning toothpick syndrome:

```
str = str.gsub(re, '<pre><code>\1</code></pre>'
```

Becomes:

```
str = str.gsub(re, "\n<pre><code>\n" + '\1' + "\n</code></pre>\n"
```

You can see what it's doing in IRB:

```
"\n<pre><code>\n" + '\1' + "\n</pre></code>\n"
=> "\n<pre><code>\n\\1\n</pre></code>\n"
```